# Execute C++ print statements in a python file

Tags: python, c++, printing, cout

i have a C++ script in which i wanted to do some cout print statements. But i want the c++ code to remmain untouched and execute and change all the c++ cout print statements with an external Python script. is there any way to do so?

Comment: So you want to use a Python script to read the C++ source, transform it (or parts of it) and write a new C++ source with your changes? Why? What is the *real* problem you need to solve?

Comment: you can check in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496733/controlling-c-output-from-python-script

Comment: Why not just [`subprocess.popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html) ?

Comment: This sounds like a classic [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You should detail your actual problem so we can help